# Migration pre-import/event listeners

Tags: 8, migrations

Before running a *User* migration, I need to get some additional information. As stated on [Events added to the migration process](https://www.drupal.org/node/2544874), it should be implemented using events; an example can be found on [Migration pre-import event/event-listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042682/drupal-8-migration-pre-import-event-event-listener).

Let's say I got my information in my `EventSubscriber` class. How do I access this data in the migration class?

Comment: What kind of information are you trying to get? Could you use the prepareRow method in your migration class (instead of using an EventSubscriber)?

Comment: @Lisa I have a number of accounts already registered on the staging. These accounts are using the same email. So basically, I want to retrieve the list of currently registered emails(before the import) so they can be skipped in prepareRow.